# Release Download Rest-API broken?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, download-link

I am trying to download the current magento 2.1.0 release:

`curl https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/filter/version/2.1.*`

Output:

```
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0.zip                               Community Edition - Full          df0857dfa076e2044e0240c3022d63cb          2016-06-23 07:14:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0.zip
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0.tar.gz                            Community Edition - Full          a1bf0c943e831dbd580c7c9fc20ff090          2016-06-23 07:18:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0.tar.gz
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0.tar.bz2                           Community Edition - Full          26754879d674e4fc358d4133cc258212          2016-06-23 07:18:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0 with Sample Data.zip              Community Edition - Full          5dedd8c445f53e6753c06d56d243dd55          2016-06-23 07:19:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0+Samples.zip
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0 with Sample Data.tar.gz           Community Edition - Full          53f790dced5fba47ad2bd7c8e8175563          2016-06-23 07:19:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0+Samples.tar.gz
Magento Community Edition 2.1.0 with Sample Data.tar.bz2          Community Edition - Full          2e3bc5d400a417dd5d45f5697e7661b5          2016-06-23 07:20:00          2.1.0          Magento-CE-2.1.0+Samples.tar.bz2
```

`curl -O https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/file/Magento-CE-2.1.0+Samples.tar.gz`

Output:

```
<h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
```

I need to download the source tarball, composer installation is not an option.

Comment: Why not try the [CE download page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download)?

Comment: I would like to be able to programmatically download installation files to my servers and found it quite silly that it seems to be such a big task.

Comment: @SteveJohnson Having to download the file to your local machine just to upload it to the server is so "FTP-era" when one could do it with wget/curl directly without any unnecessary extra steps.

I'm still just benchmarking different platforms - don't know how full-time Magento developers put up with this, I've worked for over half an hour without even being able to download the whole thing (currently downloading from the website for excruciating ~0.1 MB/s).

Comment: While testing more I figured out the problem, it's the packages with `+Samples` in the filename, pure source packages can be downloaded with REST-API without any problems (at least for v2.1.1).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am already out of the game, off to another system and I am very happy that I did so :) No responses at all to a post reporting a bug in the download API, that's weak from point. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`products/downloads/file/Magento-CE-2.1.2%2BSamples.tar.gz`

..instead of ..

`products/downloads/file/Magento-CE-2.1.2+Samples.tar.gz`

the + has to be URL encoded.